# 'Device for bootloader installation' question / Dualboot with Windows in Legacy, each OS on its own SSD

Tags: dual-boot

I have a question regarding what should I choose for "Device for boot loader installation" when installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a clean SSD while my Windows 10 is installed in another SSD.

My Windows is using Legacy BIOS, so I realized my Ubuntu must also use it/MBR instead of UEFI, otherwise the GRUB won't recognize Windows. When I first installed Ubuntu with the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu option" it was installed using UEFI, so now I want to reinstall it creating the partitions manually [following this guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts/#6b-manual-partitioning) to make sure it will use Legacy.

So where should the 'Device bootloader installation' go? On Ubuntu's SSD or on Windows'? And should it go in a specific partition or should I just select the SSD?

Comment: You always choose a drive, not a partition. And best to have Windows &  Ubuntu boot loaders on separate drives. Grub only boots working Windows, and Windows keeps turning fast start up back on preventing grub from booting it. If you have gpt partitioning, add a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with gparted and install grub-pc which is the BIOS version. I would keep the ESP - efi system partition as you should eventually totally reinstall Windows in UEFI mode. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI mode to gpt drives since 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to force grub to put all its files on the `Ubuntu-disk`. (If you don't force `grub` to do that it will install parts on both disk.) That way you can boot from disk A (Windows) or from disk B (Ubuntu)
There are 2 ways to achieve this:
1) in terminal with the command `sudo install grub /dev/sdb` (assuming that your `Windows-drive` is `sda` and your `Ubuntu-drive` is `sdb` ( check this with `GParted`)).
2) Disconnect your `Windows-drive` temporary (when the machine is turned of), install `Ubuntu`,turn the machine off and reconnect the drive.  
You can also install `Grub` on your `Windows-drive`, no problem. However if Windows has a major update, it will put it's `bootloader` in first place again, rendering `grub` unavailable. So you need to make `grub` first bootloader again. This is more work in the end.